# Refresh fragment from ViewPager when specifc tab is selected

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I would like to refresh fragment(**SentAtt**) from ViewPager. I use TabLayout to detect selected fragment but i don't know how can i refresh specific fragment when tab is selected.

```
 tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            if(tab.position==1){

                val sentAtt:SentAtt
                
            }

        }
        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly encapsulate your Fragment you should not try to refresh it from outside the Fragment.

Viewpager2 and Viewpager with BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT flag set then a Fragment will only be moved to the RESUMED state when it is selected, thus you should put you refresh code in the Fragments `onResume` method.

As the refresh code is inside the Fragment you don't work out which fragment to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

you can get fragment by tag use this code

```
tabLayout!!.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
        if(tab.position==1){

             val fragment =supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + 
    ":" 
   +
 viewPager.currentItem ) as? SentAtt
            
        }

    }
    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

    }
    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. What is R.id.pager?

Comment: Id viewpager in your xml